# In Rust What's the diff between `&` and `ref` in the for-loop

Tags: rust, iterator, pattern-matching, ref, borrow-checker

*Rust By Example* says

> A `ref` borrow on the left side of an assignment is equivalent to an `&` borrow on the right side.

Now:

```
let u = 42u32;
let x = &u;
println!("{:p}"，x);
let ref y = u;
println!("{:p}", y);
// same addr printed and that's expected

let v = [1, 2, 3];
for i in &v {
    println!("{:p}", i);
    // 0x7fff4ae23334
    // 0x7fff4ae23338
    // 0x7fff4ae2333c
    // ok, still expected
}
for ref j in v {
    println!("{:p}"，j);
    // SAME addr (and not 0x7fff4ae23334) printed for each round, WHY?
}
```

I wonder what exactly is `j` here in the `for ref j in v` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that `let ref foo = bar;` is equivalent to `let foo = &bar;`. However in for loops there is a different mechanism. In general

```rust
for foo in bar {}
```

uses [IntoIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait to "convert" `bar` to an iterator. So when you write

```rust
let v = vec![];
for foo in v {}
```

rust will use implementation [impl IntoIterator for Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-Vec%3CT,+A%3E), which will yield `T`s. However if you write

```rust
let v = vec![];
for foo in &v {}
```

rust will use implementation [impl IntoIterator for &Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a+Vec%3CT,+A%3E), which will yield `&T`s. Note that there is also implementation for [&mut Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a+mut+Vec%3CT,+A%3E).

`foo` in `for foo in bar` will bind to values returned by iterator. This is because `for` loop is a syntactic sugar that de-sugars into this (see [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#for-loops-and-intoiterator)):

```rust
{
    let result = match IntoIterator::into_iter(bar) {
        mut iter => loop {
            let next;
            match iter.next() {
                Some(val) => next = val,
                None => break,
            };
            let foo = next; /* here is the binding we provided in the for loop */
            let () = { /* loop body */ };
        },
    };
    result
}
```

Going back to our example. `for foo in &v` will bind `foo` to references to the elements of vector. This is why they each have it's own consecutive address (note that it increases by 4 bytes in each iteration - the size of `i32`). But when we say `for ref foo in bar` `ref foo` will bind to the **stack allocated variable into which value returned by the iterator is moved in each iteration** (see `next` above). Since the same stack variable is used in each iteration they all will have the same addresses, however value will be changed each time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you understand `ref` well enough. However, there's some magic happening that allows you to take a reference to a temporary variable.

For example, look at this code.

```rs
let ref a = "hello".to_string();
```

`ref a` is an [extending pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#extending-based-on-patterns). This means the string is stored in a temporary, unnamed binding that will be dropped at the end of this scope. So you could imagine it like this:

```rs
let temp = "hello".to_string();
let ref a = temp;
```

This explains why `j` is always the same address. Note that `for _ in v` consumes `v` and iterates over owned values. This happens regardless of the pattern before `in`. In other words, `let a = &b` is the same as `let ref a = b`, but `for a in &b` is not the same as `for ref a in b`. You could rewrite the for loop to look like this:

```rs
let mut v_iter = v.into_iter();
loop {
    let temp = match v_iter.next() {
        Some(x) => x,
        None => break,
    };
    let ref j = temp;
    println!("{:p}", j);
}
```

The address being printed is the address of `temp`, which stores one owned value each iteration. The value is in neither `v` nor `v_iter` when `j` is created.

Comment: This becomes more obvious when trying to iterate over a non-copy type, compiler error explains it quite well 
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=50c704e525279addf801149372e02c30